# Special case of Snake's Lemma - Neukirch Proposition 12.9

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, homological-algebra

I was wondering how Neukirch gets in his Proposition 12.9 (see [http://www.math.toronto.edu/~ila/Neukirch_Algebraic_number_theory.pdf](http://www.math.toronto.edu/%7Eila/Neukirch_Algebraic_number_theory.pdf)) from the snake-lemma long exact sequence to his claimed sequence.

He has

[image]

In particular, I don't see why the sequence is exact in the middle and at Pic(o).

Comment: Do you know how to calculate $\mathrm{coker}(\alpha, \beta, \gamma) = 1$?